# Hello how to upload an image using angularjs+mysql+node.js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

How to upload the image in angularjs and mysql and node.js?

```
<html>

   <head>
      <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "myApp">

      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
      </div>

      <script>
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

         myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var modelSetter = model.assign;

                  element.bind('change', function(){
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                     });
                  });
               }
            };
         }]);

         myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
               var fd = new FormData();
               fd.append('file', file);

               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               })

               .success(function(){
               })

               .error(function(){
               });
            }
         }]);

         myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
            $scope.uploadFile = function(){
               var file = $scope.myFile;

               console.log('file is ' );
               console.dir(file);

               var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
               fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };
         }]);

      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you facing any error or whats the actual problem with this code.

Comment: Are you trying to save the image to the DB? It is easier to copy to file to the server and save the new path to the image in the DB.

Comment: yes my bro.....i am using angularjs and node.js and mysql..........not saved the path in db when i am uploading

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs is a client side language. so it is not able to direct save data to MySql.

If any data is store in a database or in a server you must used any server side language.

You are create a web service that can tack response from client side (AngularJS) and send proper response.

**File Upload in Mysql using NodeJs**

```
fs.open(temp_path, 'r', function (status, fd) {
    if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer(getFilesizeInBytes(temp_path));
    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, 100, 0, function (err, num) {
    var query = "INSERT INTO `files` SET ?",
    values = {
               file_type: 'img',
               file_size: buffer.length,
               file: buffer
     };
    mySQLconnection.query(query, values, function (er, da) {
      if (er)throw er;
    });
  });
});

function getFilesizeInBytes(filename) {
 var stats = fs.statSync(filename)
 var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
 return fileSizeInBytes
}
```

Comment: bro i am using node.js as a server side language...but not saving the path in db of mysql....so will you plz help me to sent a coding??

Comment: How to upload file from client side(angular js) to a folder using RestAPI(node js).And Its Image location path to be saved in database.